# how to secure monitoring screen (transparent screen lock)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I know it's generally considered as insecure, but it really depends on situation. I don't want to replace valid screen lock, I want to have possibility to choose based on situation. 2 sample usecases:

kids: I want to enable her to watch show, but I would like to block 'work cooperation' on any of mine projects, and I need not to have spare hw available

at secure work site: any college need not to poke at my screen, he can trivially clone/get whatever he wants, because he has same access. So I would like to lock screen against jokers who would like to write something under my name, but while helping someone I'd like progress of some process going on my screen. Ie. ANY monitoring screen, where we want to show status 24*7, but disallow unauthorized input.

I don't expect even naive hacking attempts in these usecases, so not 100% bulletproof lock is fine.

Some time ago, there was project named pyxtrlock, but it was deprecated. Is there some replacement? Or is there better way how to secure monitoring systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyxtrlock` was just a rewrite of `xtrlock`. The original seems to satisfy your requirements. From [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/xtrlock/xtrlock.1.en.html):

> xtrlock locks the X server till the user enters their password at the
> keyboard.
>
> While xtrlock is running, the mouse and keyboard are grabbed and the
> mouse cursor becomes a padlock. Output displayed by X programs, and
> windows put up by new X clients, continue to be visible, and any new
> output is displayed normally.